# How to make videos like this

Tags: video

How can I create videos like this:

http://vimeo.com/24302498

What software do they use? I see lots of these types of videos and curious as to what they use to make them.

Comment: Nice question, I'm certainly interested too. Though I fear the answer involves a lot more than a remotely simple program.. For now. I sure hope I'm wrong about that though.

Comment: While this may not be how they did it, you can achieve similar results (not the same, but worth a look) - http://prezi.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They may have used After Effects for this. You can find tutorials on how to make it in AE [here](http://ae.tutsplus.com/tutorials/motion-graphics/design-rhythmic-motion-typography-in-after-effects/)

Its known as Typography I believe

Comment: More precisely it's called typographic animation. Typography is the art of creating and arranging type.

Answer (score 2):

Another idea is maybe Adobe Flash. It's made to make animations so something similar might be achievable.

Answer (score 1):

Not to look like a cop out answer, but I have been able to achieve similar looks using Photoshop or similar programs to create the graphics

Comment: Yeah, but the thing is that Photoshop doesn't really make moving images..

Comment: Yes it does, you can create gifs and many other things

Comment: Oh it can? I find that kind of strange, hence the name PHOTOshop ;). Alright, but I dont think you can make real videos without having to make it frame by frame? :D